# Would Extend metamagic feat increase the duration of Warlock's eldritch essences?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, metamagic

Extend spell like ability mentions:

> The creature can use that ability as an extended spell-like ability
> three times per day (or less, if the ability normally usable only once
> or twice per day). When a creature uses an extended spell-like
> ability, its duration is doubled. Spell-like abilities whose durations
> are instantaneous, concentration, or permanent are not affected. The
> creature can only select a spell-like ability duplicating a spell with
> a level less than or equal to half its caster level (round down) -1.

Based on this, can a warlock apply this feat on any of its essences such as Brimstone Blast or Beshadowed Blast to increase the duration of the effect?

**Example**: Applying Extend on Beshadowed Blast would case victim to be blinded for two rounds instead of one. With Brimstone Blast, it is calculated by 1 round per five class levels you have, so normally for a level 10 warlock target would burn for two rounds but with extend, four.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no Extend Spell-Like Ability feat in 3.0 or 3.5 (despite the fact that such a feat is referenced in the prerequisites of the Bonus Breath feat in Savage Species).  Can you give a link or book reference for the version of the feat you're using?  Is it the [3rd-party PF one from Frog God Games](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/frog-god-games/monster-feats-3pp-frog-god-games/extend-spell-like-ability/#:~:text=When%20a%20creature%20uses%20an,or%20permanent%20are%20not%20affected.)?

Comment: Alternatively, the question could be edited to reference the Sudden Extend feat, and include the quote from *Complete Arcane* saying warlocks can use Sudden metamagic feats due to their lack of spell level adjustment.